# selectattr on ansible_facts always returns an empty list

Tags: ansible

The idea is to add an item into the array if the item does not exist. The select attribute function returns an empty list even though there are items. Therefore the length of an empty is always 0, which in turn will create a new list every time in my case. So the union function in add a new comment section is returning a list with the only new comment erasing all the old ones.

I understand that the issue is with `t_array_exists["ansible_facts"]|selectattr("common_motd_qsc_comments_array", "defined")|list|length == 0` conditional statement but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried many variations of this command. Few of them are commented. Any advice/suggestion is appreciated :)

main.yml:

```yaml
- name: Get comment array from facts
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ ansible_local['snps']['motd']['comment_array'] }}"
  register: t_array_exists
  when:
    - ansible_local['snps']['motd'] is defined
    - ansible_local['snps']['motd']['comment_array'] is defined
    
- debug:
    var: t_array_exists
    
- debug:
    var: t_array_exists["ansible_facts"]|selectattr("common_motd_qsc_comments_array", "defined")|list
    # var: ansible_facts|selectattr("common_motd_qsc_comments_array", "defined")|list
    # var: t_array_exists|selectattr("common_motd_qsc_comments_array", "defined")|list
    
- name: Create an empty array if there is no array
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: []
  when:
    - t_array_exists["ansible_facts"]|selectattr("common_motd_qsc_comments_array", "defined")|list|length == 0
    
- debug:
    var: t_array_exists["ansible_facts"]|selectattr("common_motd_qsc_comments_array", "defined")|list|length
    
- name: Deleting a comment if it exists
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | difference([t_new_entry]) }}"
  loop: "{{ common_motd_qsc_delete_comment }}"
  when: t_new_entry in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
  vars:
    t_new_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"
    
- name: Add a new comment if it doesn't exist
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | union([t_new_entry]) }}"
  loop: "{{ common_motd_qsc_add_comment }}"
  when: t_new_entry not in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
  vars:
    t_new_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"
    
- name: Saving comments to snps.fact file
  ini_file:
    dest: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/snps.fact"
    section: 'motd'  # header
    option: 'comment_array'  # key
    value: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array }}"  # value
```

Ansible output:

```
TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : Get comment array from facts] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6]

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6] => {
    "t_array_exists": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "common_motd_qsc_comments_array": [
                "new comment 1"
            ]
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6] => {
    "ansible_facts|selectattr(\"common_motd_qsc_comments_array\", \"defined\")|list": []
}

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : Create an empty array if there is no array] *************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6]

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6] => {
    "t_array_exists[\"ansible_facts\"]|selectattr(\"common_motd_qsc_comments_array\", \"defined\")|list|length": "0"
}

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : Add a new comment if it doesn't exist] ******************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6] => (item=new comment 22)

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : Saving comments to snps.fact file] **********************************************************************************
changed: [ansible-poc-cos6]

TASK [common/motd_scratch/v1 : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6] => {
    "common_motd_qsc_add_comment": [
        "new comment 22"
    ]
}
```

snps.fact output:

Before:

```
[motd]
comment_array = ['new comment 1']
```

After passing new_comment as "new comment 2":

```
[motd]
comment_array = ['new comment 2']
```

Expected:

```
[motd]
comment_array = ['new comment 1', 'new comment 2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the help of my colleague. I just had to check if `comment_array is not defined` instead of trying to find its length. A simple alternate idea which works :)

```
 - name: Create an empty array if there is no array
    set_fact:
      common_motd_qsc_comments_array: []
    when:
      - ansible_local['snps']['motd']['comment_array'] is not defined
```

Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of the above in one single easy step. Here is an [MCVE](/help/mcve) playbook to illustrate.

Prior to running the playbook, I added the following file on my machine:

**`/etc/ansible/facts.d/snps.fact`**

```json
{
    "motd_example1": [
        "One message",
        "A message",
        "Message to delete"
    ],
    "motd_example2": [
        "Some messages",
        "Mandatory message",
        "Other message"
    ]
}
```

**The playbook**

```yaml
---
- name: Add/Remove list elements demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  vars:
    # The (list of) custom message(s) I want to add if not present
    my_custom_mandatory_messages:
      - Mandatory message
    # The (list of) custom message(s) I want to remove if present
    my_custom_messages_to_delete:
      - Message to delete

    # The list of custom vars I'm going to loop over for demo
    # In your case, you can simply use your single motd var
    # directly in the below task without looping. I added this
    # for convenience as the expression is exactly the same
    # in all cases. Only the input data changes
    my_motd_example_vars:
      - motd_example1
      - motd_example2
      - motd_example3  # This one does not even exist in ansible_local.snps

  tasks:
    - name: Show result using local facts for each demo test var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_local.snps[item] | default([])
          | union(my_custom_mandatory_messages)
          | difference(my_custom_messages_to_delete) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_motd_example_vars }}"

    - name: Proove it works with a totaly undefined var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ totally.undefined.var | default([])
          | union(my_custom_mandatory_messages)
          | difference(my_custom_messages_to_delete) }}"
```

**The result**

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show result using local facts for each demo test var] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=motd_example1) => {
    "msg": [
        "One message",
        "A message",
        "Mandatory message"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=motd_example2) => {
    "msg": [
        "Some messages",
        "Mandatory message",
        "Other message"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=motd_example3) => {
    "msg": [
        "Mandatory message"
    ]
}

TASK [Simple proof that it works with a totaly undefined var] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Mandatory message"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood exactly what the problem is, but if you are trying to merge two dictionaries (with one overwriting the other if the key already exists), then you might want to take a look at:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#yaml-anchors-and-aliases-sharing-variable-values

The very first example shows exactly that, with just YAML. If that doesn't do the trick, then you might want to try the `combine` filter:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries

HTH

Alex

Comment: The yaml anchor will not do the trick in any case as it can only be used in the same yaml file. OP is using local facts gathered from host wich are not defined in his playbook. Moreover, OP is manipulating a list, not a dict: So the anchor would fail here even in the same file, and the combine filter will not do the job either.